# Hibernate 2.1.1 compatibility with Oracle 12c

Tags: hibernate, oracle12c

But I do not find answer. I am migrating from Oracle 9i to Oracle 12c.

Hibernate 2.1.1 does not support Oracle 12c, but connection is normally done.
Can I use the same dialect available with hibernate 2.2.1  `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` .

I'm Project jdk 1.4+ojdbc14.jar+hibernate 2.1.1+oracle 9i to jdk 1.6+ojdbc16.jar+hibernate 2.1.1+oracle 12c Compatible question?

If you have a problem, please Just let me know in advance.

Comment: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-2-1-1-compatibility-with-oracle-12c/2891?u=hoseonsong

Comment: Hibernate 2.1.1 was released 14 years ago. Maybe this is an opportune time to update your Hibernate version.

Comment: I'm wondering that no update your Hibernate version Compatible.

Comment: No one is going to be able to answer this question. The only way you are going to answer this is to run you app and fix any issues as they arise.